# Replacing characters with unicode characters

Tags: vba, unicode

I am working with a large data file. B column of the excel sheet contains files names. However during download 2 characters get replaced (ä becomes +ñ and ö becomes +Â.) I need to be able to search with these file names so I need to reverse the names back to original.

Here is what I originally tried:

```
Private Sub scandit(n As Long)

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To n
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim d As String
a = "+" & ChrW(194) ' +
b = ChrW(132) 'ä
c = "+" & ChrW(164) ' +n
d = ChrW(148) 'ö

    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(Cells(i, 2).Value, c, b)
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(Cells(i, 2).Value, a, d)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

However this doesn't work. "+ñ" only gets removed but not replaced. Nothing happens to "+Â".

After some googling I found this:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fnd As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells.Replace what:="+" & ChrW(194), replacement:=ChrW(132), 
lookat:=xlPart
        .Cells.Replace what:="+" & ChrW(164), replacement:=ChrW(148), 
lookat:=xlPart
    End With
End Sub
```

This has the exact same problem as my own code.

Example on how the replacement should work: sy+Âd+ñ -> syödä

It would be much appreciated if someone had some ideas on how to proceed here (note that I want to do the replacement only for cells in B column.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the ChrW values and your code started working

```
Sub scandit()

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 5
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim d As String
a = "+" & ChrW(194) ' +
b = ChrW(228) 'ä
c = "+" & ChrW(241) ' +n
d = ChrW(246) 'ö

    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(Cells(i, 2).Value, c, b)
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(Cells(i, 2).Value, a, d)

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```